# Event for BeforeSave(Save As) event on previous document

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I have some kind of "warning" to avoid an Excel sheet is being used without macros enabled.
In my example it's a plain stupid rectangle on top of my first sheet that asks the user to enable his macros.
When you turn the macros on the rectangle is hidden, when the document is closed it's visible again.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 1").Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 1")).Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet 1").Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 1")).Visible = True
End Sub
```

Code works well, until the document is "saved as", the event in the BeforeClose is not triggered while saving as.
There is the "BeforeSave" event where you have a boolean value if it's "Save as" or not, but this event will be triggered on the new document that was saved, not on the old / previous one.
Problem is when I open the old document, the rectangle is not visible, because it was hidden while opening, but not set visible again through the "BeforeClose" event.

Any idea how to solve this ? I should call this code on the "previous" document before it's saved as or something like this.

Comment: Can you not have a template file? that way everytime you want to create a new file, just open the "template" file and save it as a new document?

Comment: @Zac I'm starting from a template. Once you open the template you have to save it as "full document", and after you did your thing you have to save it as a "stripped" one. The "stripped-one" is always correct, but if you open the full document again you won't see the rectangle on it.